# React testing library can't find an element with a text even though it's in the component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm learning to test my app with React testing library and jest and i have a problem when I try to check if some text is inside a component.
Basically I have a parent component (Pokemon.js) and a child component (Filters.js) and I want to verify the existence of a word written inside Filters.js by testing Pokemon.js

Here's my test :

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import Pokemon from '../../pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { TestQueryProvider } from '../helpers/test-utils'

test('Renders the Pokemon page', () => {
    render(<Pokemon />, { wrapper: TestQueryProvider });

    const { getByText } = render(<Pokemon />, { wrapper: TestQueryProvider });
    expect(getByText('Form')).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

I've tried adding screen before the getByText and I've tried to write /Form/i but it returns the same error which is

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Form. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible. 

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="sc-bjfHbI dxNTaY"
        >
          <span
            style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 
0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; max-width: 100%;"
          >
            <span
              style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: 100%;"
            >
              <img
                alt=""
                aria-hidden="true"
                src="data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%27192%27%20height=%27192%27/%3e"
                style="display: block; max-width: 100%; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"
              />
            </span>
            <img
              alt=""
              data-nimg="intrinsic"
              decoding="async"
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
              style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 
100%;"
            />
            <noscript />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div
          class="sc-bjfHbI dxNTaY"
        >
          <span
            style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 
0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; max-width: 100%;"
          >
            <span
              style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: 100%;"
            >
              <img
                alt=""
                aria-hidden="true"
                src="data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%27192%27%20height=%27192%27/%3e"
                style="display: block; max-width: 100%; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"
              />
            </span>
            <img
              alt=""
              data-nimg="intrinsic"
              decoding="async"
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
              style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 
100%;"
            />
            <noscript />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

       9 |
      10 |     const { getByText } = render(<Pokemon />, { wrapper: TestQueryProvider });
    > 11 |     expect(screen.getByText('Form')).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
      12 | })
```

The problem is that I don't know where this HTML is coming from because I've checked my code and there is nothing that has this structure.

What is my test not working ?

Edit : here's the part of Filters.js that has the text 'Form' inside

```
<PokedexDropdown>
    <label htmlFor='form'>Form</label>
    <select
        name='form'
        id='form'
        value={form}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setForm(e.target.value);
            setGeneration('all');
            setType('all');
        }}
    >
        <option value='default'>Default</option>
        <option value='regional - alola'>Regional - Alola</option>
        <option value='regional - galar'>Regional - Galar</option>
        <option value='regional - hisui'>Regional - Hisui</option>
        <option value='mega'>Mega</option>
        <option value='gmax'>Gmax</option>
    </select>
</PokedexDropdown>
```

Comment: Can you share the component that has the text `Form` in?

Comment: Is `<Filters>` conditionally rendered where its consume by any chance? Are there any network calls involved to get the filters, or network calls which have to be done before they display?

Comment: @adsy There's a useEffect before but here's a link to the whole component : [filters](https://github.com/thibaudbrault/PokeRef/blob/MigrateNext/components/Pokemon/Components/Filters.Pokemon.js)

Comment: @adsy No the component isn't conditionally rendered and there is one data fetch done in the parent component

Comment: Thanks for the link thats the context I needed. Technically it *is* conditionally rendered, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the parent component `Pokemon` makes asynchronous network calls and whilst those calls are in flight, it returns a loading display rather than the filters etc.

When you mount the component in the test, and then try to get the `Form` text straight after, this assertion is executed before the component itself has switched away from the loading state.

To fix, you typically would use `findByText` instead of `getByText` since that will poll in the background for you. You will need to `await` it as well.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import Pokemon from '../../pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { TestQueryProvider } from '../helpers/test-utils'

test('Renders the Pokemon page', async () => {
    render(<Pokemon />, { wrapper: TestQueryProvider });

    const { findByText } = render(<Pokemon />, { wrapper: TestQueryProvider });
    let formText = await findByText('Form')
    expect(formText).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Also (you might have done this already, ignore if so), you'll want to mock `https://pokeapi.co` API using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node) or something as you generally don't want to rely on external services in tests as it breaks repeatability.

Comment: Did you mock the API? you will need to, otherwise the data will never load

Comment: So I've used your code but it still returns me the HTML of my loader (the mysterious HTML which I didn't know the origin is my loading image). And when it was working (Idk why but it was working for a time) it wasn't returning the HTML of my Filters.js and the HTML inside my mapped array.

Comment: Ok I'll use the mock api but do you know why it was working for a time and why it did not return all the HTML of my page (there was only the static part but not the HTML coming from the children components and there wasn't the HTML from my mapped data) ?

Comment: Its quite possible since you hit the api a lot that you have been rate limited (this is one example of why you have to mock -- you shouldnt rely on external services in unit tests). You can find out for sure whats happening by adding a `catch` to the fetch function promise and logging the resulting error. Might want to log in `then` as well - then run the test and look at the jest output carefully to find the log line

Comment: the reason its not showing your component is presumably because theres a return null somewhere whilst its fetching?

Comment: I'm using react query and you can see my fetch hooks [here](https://github.com/thibaudbrault/PokeRef/blob/MigrateNext/helpers/DataFetch.js) and I don't think that there is a return null in my [pokemon component](https://github.com/thibaudbrault/PokeRef/blob/MigrateNext/pages/index.js)

Comment: Well, maybe not return null, but theres an early return here https://github.com/thibaudbrault/PokeRef/blob/MigrateNext/pages/index.js#L52. That all aligns with my theory since you are seeing the loader HTML. Your API request never completes, but regardless it might not be worth debugging as the real solution is mocking. I'd strongly suspect you have now been rate limited but could be any number of reasons.

Comment: If you do want to debug the api req though you'll need to use react queries `onError` functionality to log it out.,

Comment: I just checked and there is a rate limit of 300 requests per day but it was throwing this error this morning so I don't think that it's because of the rate limit. Still, I'm gonna learn to use mocking to be sure that it works. What will it log me out of when I use onError ?

Comment: If you use `onError` you ought to be able to `console.log` the error, run the test, and identify the exact problem with the request.